# How to solve route problem in blazor on latest preview of vs 2019 and .net core 3?

Tags: c#, blazor, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

When adding a new razor view or any other page it gives me the same problem

I tried to reinstall libraries but it didn't work.

@page  "/Courses"

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0115  'Template.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override BlazorUdemy C:\Users\Mohammad\source\repos\BlazorUdemy\Pages\Courses.cshtml 1   Active

Comment: There is a lot of confusion around terminology with Blazor. Blazor doesn’t use Razor Views or Razor Pages which both have .cshtml extensions. It uses components which have a .razor extension. Looking at your error, if that is meant to be a Page component then it should have a .razor extension.

Comment: @ChrisSainty that's right in the last version should work with .razor pages note .cshtml thanks

Comment: @Issac thanks dear i already solved by adding razor component not razor view or razor page